# Setup Google test in CLion

Tags: c++, googletest, linux-mint, clion

I have been sitting online for hours already trying to setup Google test on Clion in Linux but have not been able to find anything.

Can someone guide me with setting this up please?

Comment: Here is the tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Up5eNZ0FLw

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Create new Project

1. Create a repository in my ClionProjects folder

   - `cd ~/ClionProjects`
   - `mkdir .repo`
   - `cd .repo`
2. Clone the [DownloadProject](https://github.com/Crascit/DownloadProject) from github

   - `git clone https://github.com/Crascit/DownloadProject.git`
3. Create a C++ project with a src and test directory

## Add following files:

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(MyProjectName)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

### src/CMakeLists.txt

```
#set(core_SRCS ADD ALL SOURCE FILES HERE)

add_library(core ${core_SRCS})
add_executable(exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe core)
```

[We compile a library so we can include it inside the Test project]

### test/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

set(REPO ~/ClionProjects/.repo)

project(Test)

project(Example)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

#set(gtest_disable_pthreads on) #needed in MinGW
include(${REPO}/DownloadProject/DownloadProject.cmake)
download_project(
        PROJ                googletest
        GIT_REPOSITORY      https://github.com/google/googletest.git
        GIT_TAG             master
        UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1
        )

add_subdirectory(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR} ${googletest_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

#set(test_SRCS ADD ALL TEST SOURCE FILES HERE)
add_executable(runUnitTests gtest.cpp ${test_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(runUnitTests gtest gmock core)
#add_test(runUnitTests runUnitTests) #included in all tutorials but I don't know what it actually does.
```

### test/gtest.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Note: if you work yourself on a git Project it is better to include the `DownloadProject.cmake` and `DownloadProjects.CmakeLists.cmake.in` files inside the project.

Comment: I had to take out `core` from `test/CMakeLists.txt` and re-write `src/CMakeLists.txt`. After that, it worked!

Comment: @SyntaxRules Thanks.

Comment: I followed these instructions as closely as possible, but end up with a load of `Error:Configuration Debug
The source directory
 <user Dir>/CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/A32N-bdb25b84/bdb25b84/Debug/googletest-src
does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.`

Comment: For me it worked changing `gmock` to `gtest_main` at test/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @Dormathal.  This is a horrible answer leading folks who don't understand CMake to screwup their entire configuration.  You're making them rewrite their CMakeLists.txt files without understanding the impact of the changes.  A good answer explains what each change does. You could have, for instance, explained why you created additional CMakeList files.  How did this get so many upvotes is beyond me!

Comment: This was awesome! I haven't used CMake in a while, but I'm familiar with its setup, so this was kind of a breeze with your direction. I'm interviewing for a position tomorrow that is primarily for writing gtests and I haven't written gtests in a few years, so this was a great quick setup so that I can freshen my skills before tomorrow. Much thanks and kudos!

Answer (score 18):

**1.Git clone the [google-test](https://github.com/google/googletest.git) C++ test framework**

```
From https://github.com/google/googletest.git
```

**2.Include the google-test directories**

```
#Add the google test subdirectory
add_subdirectory(PATH_TO_GOOGLETEST)

#include googletest/include dir
include_directories(PATH_TO_GOOGLETEST/googletest/include)

#include the googlemock/include dir
include_directories(PATH_TO_GOOGLETEST/googlemock/include)
```

**3. Link your executable with google-test (This is after creating your executable)**

```
#Define your executable
add_executable(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${SOURCE_FILES})

#Link with GoogleTest
target_link_libraries(EXECUTABLE_NAME gtest gtest_main)

#Link with GoogleMock
target_link_libraries(EXECUTABLE_NAME gmock gmock_main)
```

Comment: This works perfectly ... Well explained (commented) answer

Comment: This is perfect. Both the google repo and clion gtest documentation does not contain a working example. This works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a small example C++11 project which uses GoogleTest](https://github.com/vdidenko/aas) which only relies on packaged *CMake* features (mainly the [`ExternalProject` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) and works both from inside *CLion* and a *nix command line.

This version shows "vendored" dependencies, which can reside outside of a project if needed. All dependency builds' source code and build artifacts are contained in the project and do not pollute the build host. The `ExternalProject` module however is fairly easy to adjust to download a specific version off of a remote repo.

Let me know if something needs clarification in README.

Comment: Link to sample project is dead.

Comment: Corrected the moved project link. The down vote was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @victor-mwenda solution, google-test should be cloned into the project directory.